# Why does \tkzMarkAngle increase the size of the following points?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

`\tkzMarkAngle` is affecting the size of the following points. Is there any logical explanation to this strange behavior?

**Without `\tkzMarkAngle`** (Normal point size)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(-3,-1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,-1){B}
\tkzDefPoint(2,2){C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

%\tkzMarkAngle[color=gray,thick,size=0.75](B,A,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[color=gray,pos=1.1](B,A,C){$\alpha$}

\tkzDrawPoints[color=red,fill=red](A,B,C)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**With `\tkzMarkAngle` BEFORE `\tkzDrawPoints`** (Increased point size)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(-3,-1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,-1){B}
\tkzDefPoint(2,2){C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

\tkzMarkAngle[color=gray,thick,size=0.75](B,A,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[color=gray,pos=1.1](B,A,C){$\alpha$}

\tkzDrawPoints[color=red,fill=red](A,B,C)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**With `\tkzMarkAngle` AFTER `\tkzDrawPoints`** (Normal point size)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(-3,-1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,-1){B}
\tkzDefPoint(2,2){C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

\tkzDrawPoints[color=red,fill=red](A,B,C)

\tkzMarkAngle[color=gray,thick,size=0.75](B,A,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[color=gray,pos=1.1](B,A,C){$\alpha$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't quite understand what happens, but seems like the `thick` option becomes "active", and thus used in `\tkzDrawPoints` as well. If you do `\tikzset{thin}` after `\tkzMarkAngle` the size of the points doesn't change.

Comment: My workaround is `\tkzDrawPoints[color=red,fill=red,size=3](A,B,C)`. The `size=3` does the job.

Comment: When you get this kind of problem a good solution is to insert the commands in a group .

Answer (score 4):

No problem with the new version (beta) of tkz-euclide [Euclide v 2.40b](http://altermundus.fr/files/euclide/geom_2.40b.zip)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(-3,-1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,-1){B}
\tkzDefPoint(2,2){C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

\tkzMarkAngle[color=gray,thick,size=0.75](B,A,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[color=gray,pos=1.1](B,A,C){$\alpha$}

\tkzDrawPoints[color=red,fill=red](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]